# Why animation-duration property is not working

Tags: css, animation, loading, duration

I am trying to make an **animated loading text**. But here my ***duration property*** is not working.

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="Text">
        Loading<span class="l1">.</span><span class="l2">.</span><span class="l3">.</span>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
    .l1{
    visibility:hidden ;
    color:red;
    animation-name:dots;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite ;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
    
    
}

.l2{
    visibility:hidden ;
    color:red;
    animation-name:dots;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite ;
    animation-delay:1s;
    
}

.l3{
    visibility:hidden ;
    color:red;
    animation-name:dots;
    animation-duration:3s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite ;
    animation-delay:1.5s;
    
}

@keyframes dots{
    from{visibility:hidden ;}
    to{visibility:visible ;}
}
```

But the **duration property** is not working. The three dots are appearing one after another, but they stay constantly visible after appearing all the three dots.
But I want to make the all the three dots disappear again after appearing and to repeat it infinite time.
Thank you

Comment: That's not what duration do. It defines the timespan required to complete the animation (one cycle)

Answer (score 1):

Because aniamation takes palce on progressive properties.

Thus use `opacity: 0` > `opacity: 1`

which will allow the animation to trasit from `0` to `1` gradually through the fractional numbers based on `delay`

*P.S.*
remove `visibility:hidden` from all `li` classes

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .l1, .l2, .l3{
    display:inline-block ;
    opacity: 0;
    color:red;
    animation:dots 1.5s infinite ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 .l1{
    animation-delay:0.5s;    
}

.l2{
    animation-delay:1s;    
}

.l3{
    animation-delay:1.5s;    
}

@keyframes dots{
    0%{opacity:1 ;}
    100%{opacity:0 ;}
}
```

```html
<div id="Text">
        Loading<span class="l1">.</span><span class="l2">.</span><span class="l3">.</span>
    </div>
```